# What does it mean to include a p-value in an exploratory factor analysis?

Tags: factor-analysis

I have been informed that I should have a p value listed in my EFA results section?
I am confused by this and wonder what am I missing?

Comment: For what hypothesis test? Can you ask the person who told you this?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the p-value refers to the  chi-square goodness of fit test that you commonly get from programs like SPSS when you run exploratory factor analysis with maximum likelihood extraction.

It is basically a test of whether there is a systematic difference between the correlation matrix implied by the factor structure and the observed correlation matrix. It is sometimes used as a test of whether you have extracted enough factors. For example, if it is significant, then some people would say that you should extract more factors.

That said, there are issues with this test. Typically there will  be some difference between the factor structure implied by extracted solution and the observed correlations. As such, the p-value is often a test of statistical power. With large samples, very small differences will be statistically significant. With small samples, large differences wont be statistically significant.